# Saving mongo data in Windows host

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to save mongodb data in Windows host, but getting an error, I want this to be happen through Docker-compose only

My Docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD:
    volumes:
    - C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Data:/data/db

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD:
volumes:
  C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Data:
```

**Getting this error 
Volume value 'C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Data' doesn't match with any of the regexes: '[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$'**

I tried with

```
volumes:
  - /C/Users/sd/Desktop/Data:/data/db
```

and

```
volumes:
  - //C/Users/sd/Desktop/Data:/data/db
```

but still the same issue

Comment: The given regex: `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+$` does not match `C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Data:` but `C:\Users\sd\Desktop\Data`. Maybe you got a colon at your definition - or you have got an invisible character in your config being not printed.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax should work (notice the minus c ) :

> volumes: - //c/Users/sd/Desktop/Data:/data/db

In addition, you should add the COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS variable :

[As described here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_convert_windows_paths)

Comment: I tried with 
volumes: - //c/Users/sd/Desktop/Data:/data/db and I have already added COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS variable = true
but still the same error message

Comment: Did you restart docker after setting the environment variable ?

Comment: Yes I did, even i restarted the VM as well

Comment: Ho, I did not notice that you got two definition of the volume. Could you try to remove the last one ? The volume directive at at the end of the file aim to declare named volume.

Comment: Hey, found a different solution for now, as I am using docker volume instead of windows directory. Thanks anyways